# Sort Firebase data in descending order

Tags: java, android, sorting, firebase-realtime-database, leaderboard

I want to create a highscores ListView with entries being displayed in descending order, with the use of orderByValue I am getting them sorted in ascending order however when using Collections.reverse() with my arraylist, the entries are still not reversed in the ListView.

```
 private Query reference; //database reference
private ListView ListView; //creating listview
private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; //creating array adapter
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_high_scores);


    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Highscores").orderByValue(); //reference the highscore section in database



    ListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view); //find the list view in the xml


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList); // set the adapter to the list
    Collections.reverse(arrayList);

    ListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { // add a child listener for the database
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(); // convert the values in the databse to string
            arrayList.add(value); //add them to the arraylist
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify that the dataset has changed



        }
```

the data in the database is

{
  "-M4FPEiJ_DVc9kaQrebz" : 0,

"-M4FPIuMbArT6KjtrDtO" : 6,

"-M4FPP5EdC1CaKgOVECX" : 17,

"-M4FPTWg7JkKRvWakRkH" : 12,

"-M4FPYPNVZIjhBM6gVWW" : 11,

"-M4FPbL9I-fsQwRvVIFX" : 5
}

Answer:

Managed to fix this by simply adding to the arraylist at 0 index no matter what, all other elements were simply shifted to the right leading to a listview in descending order.

```
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(); // convert the values in the databse to string
            arrayList.add(0, value); //add them to the arraylist
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify that the dataset has changed
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the data at `Highscores` in your database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can order the result descending.

Answer (score 0):

reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { // add a child listener for the database
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

```
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(); // convert the values in the databse to string
        arrayList.add(value); //add them to the arraylist
        Collections.reverse(arrayList);  //add this line for short solution

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify that the dataset has changed



    }
```

Comment: Tried doing this but does not seem to work, the original entries were in order (0,6,17,12,11,5). After adding your suggestion, in the ListView they are displayed in the order (17,11,5,0,6,12)

Comment: reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Highscores").orderByValue();
Try remove orderByValue() from this
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Highscores”);